# How do I programmatically create a Tab with EditText in it?

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

My app's text editor lets a user open and edit files, I want to open the file as a new tab in the TabHost so multiple files can be open. How do I add an EditText to a newly created Tab? This is what I tried in my onCreate()

```
TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();
        EditText editor = new EditText(this);
        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(editor.getId());
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");
```

I assume the problem is `spec1.setContent(editor.getId());

Comment: Can you post your `xml`?

Comment: xml is not relevant here

Comment: Didn't think so :) Trying your answer Rafael. 1 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to set an id (which was not defined by the way) as a layout id.
It won't work that way. Try:

```
TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();
        EditText editor = new EditText(this);
        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setIndicator(editor);
```

if this is what you want. You can also try:

```
TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
            tabHost.setup();
            final EditText editor = new EditText(this);
            TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
            spec1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
                 public View createTabContent(String tag){
                     return editor;
                 }
             });
```